# Как присвоить объекты из формы к объектам в функции

Tags: c++, qt, функции

У меня есть функция: `func1()`.

В func1() выполняются действия, допустим :

```
int func1(int value) {
   value = ui->lineEdit->text().toInt;  
   return value;
}
```

Как сделать, чтобы при вызове функции менялись объекты `value` и `lineEdit` на другие, уже существующие в другой функции, допустим `lineEdit` на `lineEdit_2`, а `value` на `value_2`.

И со всеми изменёнными объектами совершались одиннаковый действия, как и с изначальными.

Comment: А что значит уже существующие в другой функции? Вторая функция запускается и ждет первую что ли?) Просто здесь вопросы тогда к области видимости у меня

Comment: `lineEdit_2` и `value_2`. Типа похожие объекты в разных функциях, и действия с ними надо совершить одиннаковые

Comment: Ну тогда передавайте в функцию ссылки на объекты с которым надо производить действия.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что тупо надо swap сделать?

Comment: @Slav9n92 я тупо не понимаю, что за swap?))) Куда надо всё сдвигать?

Comment: @VTT а их надо передавать при вызове или же в самой её реализации?

Comment: И там, и там. Так же как и `value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Всё оказалось чрезвычайно просто! Надо было просто вспомнить те самые первые азы из книги, где есть надпись "для начинающих" =))*

Надо в func1() в аргументах поставить типы объектов, с которыми мы хотим производить все действия. Допустим,

```
double func1(double value, QString str) {
 if(ui->lineEdit->text() == str) {
    value = 2,5;
   }
    return value;
}
```

Дальше в вызове функции подставляем уже на нужные нам объекты:

```
 double valueTime;

 func1(valueTime, "Time")
```

Взаместо изначальных value и str подставляем объекты, c которыми будут выполнятся те же действия. В случае с str мы подставили значение, а не сам объект.

Всё =)

P.S. пример выдуман от балды, так что не надо на меня ругаться из-за этого.

Answer (score 1):

тогда предлагаю такой вариант

```
QObjectList widgetList = ui->centralWidget->children();

for( const auto& a: widgetList){
    qDebug() << a;
}
```

таким образом можно получить список ваших виджетов, и делать с ними все что захочется

Comment: Нет, надо сделать, чтобы они не менялись местами, а с ними происходили одни и те же действия. Допустим, у меня 100 этих value. И мне с каждым проводить полностью все операции долго. Поэтому в `func1()` прописывается действия с `value` в `lineEdit`, а дальше эту функцию вызывают в других, меняя просто объекты на `value1`, `lineEdit1`; `value2`, `lineEdit2`... . Возможно это оно и есть, что Вы показали, но мне кажется, это не то...

Comment: Согласен, у меня ваще не то.

Comment: Можно ли указать какие-то определённые виджеты? Если да, то как?